# Вопрос по Random в java

Tags: java, случайные-числа

```
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int rInt = r.nextInt(2);
while (rInt != 2) {
    System.out.println(rInt);
    r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    rInt = r.nextInt(2);
}
```

Почему такая конструкция выдает только 0 и 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что Вы указываете генерировать целые значения от 0 до 2 не включительно.

Из документации:

> public int nextInt(int bound) ... bound - the upper bound (exclusive)

То есть если Вам нужно, что бы генерировались значения от 0 до 2 включительно то нужно указывать значение аргумента 3.

Comment: Не нашел где это описано, спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что метод `nextInt(int n)` возвращает случайное число в диапазоне `[0, n)`, само значение `n` исключено из диапазона, о чем явно говорится в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)):

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (**exclusive**)

Думайте об аргументе `n`, как о количестве разных чисел, которые вы можете получить, начиная с нуля, из расширенного натурального ряда.